# SOCKS5 proxy with username authentification for windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, socks-proxy

Can you suggest any SOCKS5 proxy server for Windows (ideally Windows 7) which supports SOCKS5 username authentification ([rfc 1929](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1929.txt)).

Answer (score 1):

HandyCache is completely graphical and supports SOCKS5 access, and has many other features, like caching files, forwarding certains URLs to external proxy servers, URL rewriting and blacklists. The free version has a limit of five users but is completely functional, so if you don't have more users than that, give it a try. I've been using it on my personal computer for a long time. The monitor shows all recent requests (along with the usernames if you set up that) and how the proxy processed them:

[image: HandyCache monitor]

Here's the [download page](http://handycache.ru/component/option,com_remository/Itemid,2/func,fileinfo/id,43/) for the current version. Click on Скачать (download), and just extract the zip file. If the program is in Russian when you open it, use the menu located in this area of the first option tab to change the language to English (there's also an [English language forum](http://handycache.ru/component/option,com_smf/Itemid,10/board,12.0/)):

[image: Handycache main options tab]

The "Access" tab is where you set up your users and the SOCKS5 access port.

Comment: Yes, new HandyCache is quite interesting. Unfortunatelly their SOCKS5 implementation doesn't work with passwords. Maybe they've implemented anything else but plain username/passworld authentification. At least Dropbox can't use it in that mode. Hope they will fix it in the future. Nevertheless, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: SOCKS5 support was actually added recently. Maybe if you make a post on the official forum, mai6 will accept your suggestion. He usually replies to all posts.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [3proxy](http://www.3proxy.ru/), it is tiny, free, and works on Windows and Linux. It has built-in username/password auth support, although I've never used it myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried 3proxy, it works fine without authentification. But unfortunatelly it doesn't follow rfc1929 for username/passworld authentification (when 3proxy is configured with "auth=strong"). BTW, dropbox doesn't work with it in this case.